# swift 3.0 rotate image horizontally

Tags: swift, image

[image]What I need is to rotate image horizontally, and I am using UIView.animate and it works fine, but the problem is the position of the image changed when it rotate. I tried to use anchor point, but it did not work.

What I have to do to not change the position when the image is rotating?

This is my code :

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.5, options: 
    [.repeat,.curveEaseInOut,.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: {
        targetView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1);
    }) { finished in

    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you could share the chunk of code where this is located, that would be great. Otherwise, it's harder to help you.

Comment: @bearacuda13 it is edited

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's rotating it. I think the problem is that your code just moves it.

**Swift 3, 4**

```
func rotateView(view:UIView) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in

        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * .25)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Usage:

```
rotateView(targetView)
```

Let me know if I'm completely wrong :)

Comment: Thanks @bearacuda13, but my question is how to make the imageview rotate horizontally on axe X. like it enter to the screen.

Comment: I’m quite confused... you mean flip it over the x axis?

Comment: Hello @bearacuda, As you see in the image I added now, I want the image to rotate like the middle image on the Y axis. (sorry not x).